# List of pointers to different types of objects

Tags: c++

What would be the best way to implement a list of pointers to different types in C++?

I thought of doing something like this:

```
enum MyType {...};
typedef std::pair<MyType, void*> Ptr;
std::vector <Ptr> list;
```

And then doing the suitable static typecast as soon as I need to access one of the objects in the list.

Another approach would be having different vectors for each object type:

```
std::vector<ClassA*> list_a;
std::vector<ClassB*> list_b;
...
```

The issue is that I need to implement a graph where not all vertices have the same type.

EDIT. Performance is critical. The more efficient the code is the better.

Comment: There's always `boost::variant`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best solution would be to have all the classes inherit from the same class and store pointers to the base class in the list. Only use a `void*` as a last and very,very dangerous solution.

Comment: How would I convert from the base class to the derived class? With a dynamic_cast? Any performance penalty involved? I forgot to mention that performance is critical and code should be very efficient. Thanks

Comment: Yes, to convert from a pointer to base class you need to use `dynamic_cast`. the other solution is to have the base class define a general interface that all child classes will implement and then no cast will be needed.

Comment: Well, I need `dynamic_cast`. A general interface is a requirement hard to meet in this case. But I'm concerned about performance penalties...

Comment: If you use void* you will still have to cast in order to use the methods of your objects.

Comment: You can use the static typecast in the case I suggest too. But this is *dagerous* trust me debugging and maintaining your code will turn into hell. You don't want to go there.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Maybe I can implement it with a base class and later compare the performance of both solutions (static vs dynamic cast) in order to assess if the static one is worth using.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather define a common super-class for all the nodes of your graph, e.g.

```
class Node {
   // probably some fields giving siblings, or at least a unique number
};

class GreenNode : public Node {
    // etc...
};

class YellowNode : public Node {
};

class BlackLeaf : public Node {
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Have all the different types of vertex inherit from a base `Vertex` class, then use a list of `Vertex*`.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned it is better to use base class + its descendants. But if you really want to use C structs for nodes, then you can use a common "C"-style approach - put in the beginning of the each struct some field (let it be int field) to describe a type of the node. It helps you to find out what type each node has:

```
typedef enum {
  SMALL_NODE = 1,
  NORML_NODE,
  HUUGE_NODE,
} type;

struct small_node {
  unsigned int type; /* type above - SMALL_NODE */
  /* ... */
};

struct norml_node {
  unsigned int type; /* type above - NORML_NODE */
  /* ... */
};

struct huuge_node {
  unsigned int type; /* type above - HUUGE_NODE */
  /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three options depending on your criteria:

1. Use a void* pointer: this is explicit in telling any reader of your code "type information is being removed". This covers all cases, but it is entirely up to you to ensure that the type information is retrievable elsewhere it is going to be needed.
2. Use intrusive-polymorphism, whereby you define a class required for membership in this list, and have to inherit it into any class that wants to be pointed to.

   ```
   struct ListInterface { // struct for defaulting to public
       void Poke(uint addr, uint value) = 0;
       uint Poke(uint addr) const = 0;
   };

   class SplineVertex : public Vertex, public ListInterface {
       ...
   };
   ```
3. Use non-intrusive polymorphism, whereby you create a derived class from any class that wants membership.

   ```
   struct ListInterface { // struct for defaulting to public
       void Poke(uint addr, uint value) = 0;
       uint Poke(uint addr) const = 0;
   };

   class SplineVertex : public Vertex {
       ...
   };

   class SplineVertexHolder : public SplineVertex, public ListInterface {
   };
   ```